# Check if textbox contains text, if it does then send

Tags: javascript, html

I have this email form, with "Sender, "Subject" and "Message".

But i haven't linked it to make sure they have written something, so if someone press the "Send" button without typing anyting, i get a blank email. So i want it to abort the email sending if the textbox is empty, and send it if it contains any text.

code for the send button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
```

ID for the textbox is: `textbox_text`

Comment: Do this on the server-side. You can do it on the client-side, but since the client can modify the client-side, everything you do on the client side can be bypassed.

Comment: **DO NOT** use the name `submit` on form elements.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Accessing the text box? or in forming a condition to check if it is empty? or canceling the submit event? Try something and then post your issues. This is something very basic that every one can do by doing few google search.

Comment: Even if you check it on client side, you will have to put a sanity check on server.

Comment: Why not just add the attribute `required`?

Comment: @adeneo Why not use "submit" on form elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java Script function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function IsEmpty()
{
 if(document.forms['frm'].textbox_text.value == "")
    {
      alert('Message body is empty');
      return false;
    }
      return true;
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="frm">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return IsEmpty();" value="Submit"     class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

**EDIT** Check textbox2 in if condition

```
if(document.forms['frm'].textbox1.value == "" && document.forms['frm'].textbox2.value == "")
```

Comment: You are missing `return false;` / `return true`. Your code lets the form be submitted.

Comment: Thanks! But how do i check if both textbox1 and textbox2 is empty?

Comment: @xc123e1 You can check multiple conditions in if stament

Comment: @CharanGhate - So i can do: if( document.getElementById('textbox21').value =="" && document.getElementById('textbox2').value =="")

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to validate the form like this-

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  Sender
  <input type="text">
  <br/>Subject
  <input type="text">
  <br/>Message
  <input type="text" id="txtMessage">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" name="btnSend">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=btnSend]").click(function() {
      var msg = $("#txtMessage").val();
      if (msg == "") {
        alert("Please enter the message");
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this is your exact answer but it will helps you to validate:

```
$('#checkSubmit').click(function(){
     var chec=$("#textContent").val();
    if(chec=="")
        alert("Please add your content");
    else
        alert("successfully submitted");
});
```

check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0t3oovoa/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it two ways:

1. Client Side( Which i recommend) use the form validation to validate the form data if it is empty tell them to fill it. You chose the submit button to trigger validation that is not recommended instead validation is triggered on form submission or on change of input elements(for real-time validation). Anyways below is an example for validation using the click event on submit button.

```
 var validateTextBox = function(textBox) {
     var val = textBox.value;
     if(val=="") {   // Check for empty textbox
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
 documnet.querySelector('#SubmitButton').onclick(function () {
  var textbox = document.querySelector("#SubjectORMessage").value;
  if(validateTextBox(textbox)){
    // Do something to let page know that form is valid
  } else {
    // Let the user know that he has done something wrong
    alert("Please fill the content");
  }
})
```

2. Server Side if unfortunately empty data is send to the server, then use server side validation (Server side validation requires a little more thing to do at more than one place, i.e., html, php/python/perl)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that on server side (with php) and you can also check it on client side(Javascript).

Client side test is good if you want the user to get fast response, but you still need to check it on server side because javascript on your website can ALWAYS be changed by user.

You could also just add "required" on your input elements.

for server side check with php:

```
<?php
//Check if variables exist
if(isset($_POST['sender']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
    //Check if sender value is empty
    if(empty($_POST['sender'])){
      //If empty, go back to form.Display error with $_GET['error'] in your form page
      header('location: backToFormPage.php?error=send');
    }
    //...
}
//Variables doesn't exist
else{
//Redirect to page or other action
}

?>
```